# Preserve indent across lines in the editor

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editor

One of the limitations of the text editor is encountered when working with text that includes indentation.

For instance, if I type in 4 spaces to start a new level of indent, I have to type in 4 spaces for every subsequent line with the same level of indent. This gets worse if the text includes multiple levels of indentation; 3 levels of indent would mean typing in 16 spaces  which is not uncommon especially if you are working with source code on sites like Stack Overflow. It would be great if the cursor stays at the same level when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> \ <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Of course, you can always use another text editor, but it'd be great if the editor here could do that.

Comment: How often to you write source code directly in SO, compared to using your favorite editor and testing it works before pasting it into an SO window?

Comment: I use ctrl+k after finished writing code generally.

Comment: Stack Exchange can't be the only place on the Internet in need of a more advanced (code) inline editor. Aren't there some examples of front runners regarding this on the entire Internet?

Comment: Some call this feature [auto-indentation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14297/completely-disable-all-auto-indentation) or [auto-indent](https://www.emeditor.com/forums/topic/indent/#post-25462).

Comment: Press `Shift`+`Enter`. Or simply use code fences instead.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're *not* asking for indenting any

```
Code
```

which requires one empty line plus 4 blanks.

According the documentation, such kind of autoindenting is not possible so far.

You can do either by copy 4 blanks and paste them required times.
But you can ask for a feature request. However, I don't expect, that it get's accepted.

Comment: *indenting is not possible so far* Why not? It's possible..

Comment: Indenting in general is possible of course, but not in the way the requestor asked for.